# iTextSharp support for .NET Framework 4.5.1

Tags: itext, .net-4.5

We are planning to use iTextSharp in our .NET application. Does iTextSharp support all framework versions of .NET? specifically .NET Framework v4.5.1

Are there any scenarios where certain features of iTextSharp work only in a particular version of .NET?

Comment: `iTextSharp` is notorious for its Documentations. So validating it against the documentations would be tough. Possibly, someone with hand-on experience can only help or you can jump into and start with a POC kind of stuff! Good Luck!

Comment: iTextSharp supports all framework versions from 2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Install-Package iTextSharp -Version 5.5.13.3